# Statements not executing in order? (defvar within a let statement)

Tags: common-lisp, let

I've tried to reduce it to the minimal example. The code runs without an error, producing the expected output. But it gives me a warning that my first variable is undefined. It seems that the second statement of progn doesn't "see" the results of the first statement. Thanks for the help!

(I originally did not have the progn construct in the code at all, but after getting this error I added it to see if that would force execution in order -- but the error is the same.)

Here's the code:

```
(let ((input (open "input.lisp")))
  (progn (defvar var1 (read input))
         (defvar arr1 (make-array var1 :initial-contents (read input))))
  (close input))

(print var1)
(print arr1)
```

These are the contents of the file "input.lisp":

```
9
(10 8 6 4 2 4 6 8 10)
```

And this is the output I get from sbcl after executing (load "test.lisp"):

```
; in: DEFVAR ARR1
;     (MAKE-ARRAY VAR1 :INITIAL-CONTENTS (READ INPUT))
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: VAR1
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     VAR1
;   caught 1 WARNING condition

9 
#(10 8 6 4 2 4 6 8 10) 
T
```

So, it seems to me that both definition statements are executing, but the second doesn't "see" the results of the first. It still constructs the array correctly because it's filled with the given initial-contents. But why isn't var1 already defined?

Comment: You should always surround lexical variables with earmuffs. You should call them *var1* and *arr1*. Otherwise you will run into trouble. And I don't want to read your code.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by earmuffs? I only called the variables that because I wanted this minimal working example to be clear. [... edited out blah blah blah...]. Edit: I looked up earmuffs. Thanks for the advice. The problem I'm having is it seems like either a) practically all my variables need to be global ("lexical"?), or b) I just want to wrap everything in huge nested let statements. Is there a good middle ground?

Comment: Earmuffs are stars surrounding the variable name. You undoubtedly stumbled on them before. You don't have to take my word for it, rather read the opinion of a true professional (Nikodemus): http://random-state.net/log/3498750808.html.

Comment: Oh yes, I see that earmuffs are good, but if these variables are so special, it makes me think I have too many of them.... Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: whoplisp is a bit confused. It's conventional that *special* variables (declared by `defvar`) get the earmuffs, not lexical variables (declared by `let`). It's only a convention, so you don't have to follow it if you don't like it, but it's worth knowing about if you ever need to read code written by other Lisp programmers.

Comment: Is "special variable" a technical term here?  I did get whoplisp's meaning correctly, I kind of parsed "lexical" as "global".... But you're defining special variable as anything declared by defvar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [documentation for `defvar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm) in the Hyperspec:

> If a `defvar` or `defparameter` form appears as a top level form, the compiler must recognize that the name has been proclaimed `special`.

This implies (and it seems to be the case for SBCL) that if a `defvar` appears as a non-top-level form, then the compiler need not recognize that the name has been declared. So how come your `defvar`s are not being compiled as top level forms? See [section 3.2.3.1, Processing of Top Level Forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bca.htm) (point 6) for the answer: the `let` surrounding your code causes it to be compiled as non-top-level forms.

So you need to `defvar` your variables at top level, and then assign them later on with `setf` inside the `let`.

---

Like this. It's also usually simpler to use [`with-open-file`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_open.htm) rather than `open` and `close`.

```
(defvar var1)
(defvar arr1)

(with-open-file (input "input.lisp" :direction :input)
  (setf var1 (read input))
  (setf arr1 (make-array var1 :initial-contents (read input))))

(print var1)
(print arr1)
```

---

The reason that you are having this trouble is that you are placing your code at top level in the file. This is a slightly unusual thing to do: the normal Lisp coding style is to put most of your code in function definitions, and then to call those functions when you need to run them.

For example, this would be a more typical way to write this kind of code, with the initialization code in its own function.

```
(defvar *var1* nil "Documentation for var1.")
(defvar *arr1* nil "Documentation for arr1.")

(defun init-from-file (file)
  "Read *var1* and *arr1* from file."
  (with-open-file (input file :direction :input)
    (setf *var1* (read input))
    (setf *arr1* (make-array *var1* :initial-contents (read input)))))

(when (null *var1*) (init-from-file "input.lisp"))
```

Comment: OK, thanks, that makes sense. I didn't really "get" toplevel forms but I think I understand....

Comment: Does that mean I have to write "(defvar input (open "input.lisp"))" since I can't use the "let" construct?

Comment: See code. You can use `let` if you prefer, but `with-open-file` is better in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to use a macro to define and each variable according to the input, which is why the defvars were in the let statement in the first place. Any advice on that? Should I define the variables first and have the macro just setf each one?

Comment: That would be one approach, or (depending on exactly what you are doing) you could have the macro generate the whole thing: `defvar`, `setf` and all.